# Uninitialized field with non-null literal string type is undefined despite strict null checks?

Tags: typescript

I believe the behaviour illustrated below is a bug in Typescript, and opened https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15170.  The code example in that issue demonstrates the issue more clearly than the code below.

---

Consider the following code in `undefined-literal-string-field.ts`:

```ts
class Foo {
  public foo: 'foo';
}

const foo = new Foo();

console.log('Foo ', foo.foo);
```

**Note** that `Foo.foo` has a [literal string type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) but does **not** include `undefined`.  In other words note that the type is just `'foo'`, but **not** `'foo' | undefined`.

In Typescript 2.2 this code compiles **with `--strictNullChecks`**:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 2.2.2    
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc --strictNullChecks undefined-literal-string-field.ts
```

However, the field is **`undefined` at runtime**:

```
$ node undefined-literal-string-field.js
Foo  undefined
```

Obviously that's because it's not initialized in the resulting JS code:

```js
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
var foo = new Foo();
console.log('Foo ', foo.foo);
```

I may have misunderstood `--strictNullChecks`, but as far as I see this flag should prohibit `undefined` as value unless the type is a union with `undefined`, i.e. `'foo' | undefined`.  That's not the case here.

Why does the Typescript compiler allow me to access an **uninitialized field** whose type **does not allow the value `undefined`**?  Isn't that plain unsound?

And—given that `foo`'s type only allows a single value—why doesn't the compiler automatically initialize it with this one value it's allowed to have?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you expect a non initialized value would have? It's not like typescript would automagically assign it. Any value that hasn't been assigned is undefined (which is not the same as null). What I see from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) is that your definition restrict the values it can have (you cannot assign anything else than foo), not that it must have exactly that value. So I am rather saying it's something you got wrong, without defaulting it to `foo` it is not set

Comment: @Icepickle I expect the compiler to reject that code. With strict null checks undefined is not a value assignable to foo's type; yet the property is implicitly assigned that value.  Perhaps my understanding of the type system is too strict, but to me that looks like unsound behaviour, and I'm curious whether that's intentional.

Comment: @Icepickle In other words, I'd expect that behaviour *without* strict null checks. But *with* strict null checks that's surprising to say the least.

Comment: I agree in so far that you cannot assign `undefined` to it, but that also doesn't happen in your code. The default value for a variable that hasn't got assigned anything is `undefined` that's just how javascript/typescript works. Just assign it a default value and you are fine (the only thing you have is a type safety that never anything else but `foo` would be assigned)

Comment: @Icepickle So, in Typescript a variable is—under certain circumstances—allowed to have a value that's not assignable to its type?! Doesn't that sort of defeat the whole purpose of the type system?  Means I can't rely on the type system to catch accidentally uninitialised variables?

Comment: As far as I understand I would say so, from the docs I do not see any restriction that mentions that a single value literal string type is automatically assigned it's single value. But don't shoot the messenger, that is just how I understand / read it from the docs

Comment: If I btw, check [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html) it also mentions that it only restricts assignment and the same is also mentioned [here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/03/31/string-literal-types-in-typescript). Also note, that `undefined` is not `null` so I don't see that the compiler flag would add anything to it. In fact, in case you use this flag, all conditional types would automatically add `| undefined` to it (as seen from the docs as well)

Comment: @Icepickle Strict null checks *do* restrict both null *and* undefined (try it!); that's why this behaviour comes unexpected to me.  I'll open an issue with Typescript; I can't believe this is intentional; it'd defeat all undefined checks.

Comment: In assigning yes, but your code doesn't assign anything. I am curious how the ticket will be handled, any change you can put the link to the issue here as well? :)

Comment: @Icepickle I think we've got a different understanding of "assignable".  To me (and when talking about type systems in general) it doesn't refer to actual assignments; rather, you say a value V is assignable to a type T when a variable of that type T is allowed to have the value V, and I read the TS docs in that sense.

Comment: I agree, that's why I would be interested in seeing how an issue with TS people would evolve. Maybe it was an oversight on their part, but from a javascript perspective, I see it as `undefined`. And since TS is nothing more but a type safe fancy transpiler, I don't see how it would handle javascript properties differently as long as no assignment is made. So I can follow you that it should behave in an enum way, but I don't see it from the specs

Comment: @lunaryorn I understand your concern.I think you're right. I think that the compiler should error if you don't initialize a variable in strictNullChecks env, either in the declaration directly or in the constructor. Maybe worth looking for an issue about it with TypeScript, and if there isn't one, open one.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha He did, the link is up in the post. It would apparently be a breaking change implementing the desired behavior (or at least in how far it has been discussed till now)

Answer (score 1):

As You've wrote the `foo` field is not initialized in Your code. Compiler wont rise any error in the `console.log` line because from his point of view, the object of class `Foo` have such field (either its initialized or not is a different story that compiler wont need to worry about).

Regarding the second question `why the compiler wont initialize the field?` the answer is simple - the `foo: 'foo'` definition is just a **type** definition. Initializing an properly value should be done by purpose in the code.

If You want the `foo` to have default value that will be initialized You can change the class to:

```
class Foo {
    public foo: 'foo' = 'foo';
}
```

This should initialize it properly.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't answer my question. I tried to clarify it wrt the interaction between `strictNullChecks` and uninitialized fields, i.e. why the compiler effectively allows the value `undefined` for a field that is **not allowed to be `undefined`** as per its type.  The compiler **must** reject this code in my understanding; the current behaviour is plain unsound in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have initalised the object

```
const foo =new Foo();
```

When you are using the below code

```
class Foo {

  public foo : 'foo';

}
let foo: 'foo';

console.log('Foo ', foo.foo);
```

This will throw

```
 error TS2454: Variable 'foo' is used before being assigned.
```

You are missing the assignment operator which should be

```
public foo= 'foo';
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't seem to answer my question either.